# RSelenium script getting unhappy Chrome face

Tags: r, google-chrome, selenium, rselenium

I have the code:

```
    startServer(args = c("-port 4456"), log = FALSE, invisible = FALSE)
    selServ <- startServer(args = c("-port 4456", "-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/Drivers/chromedriver"), log = TRUE) 
    remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName="chrome", port=4456)
    remDr$open()
```

I have the latest Chrome driver in C:\Drivers\chromedriver.exe.
When I run the code, the server starts but I get the unhappy Chrome face and error [image: MY exact issue]
The same driver works with my Python and C# scripts but they are using WebDriver.
Does anyone know what could be causing this error or how to use WebDriver with R?

Comment: In your code you have started two Selenium Servers. Your first line of code starts a Selenium Server without reference to the location of chrome driver.

Answer (score 0):

You start two Selenium Servers with your code. The call to chrome driver is an
argument for the JVM and should be passed as an argument in `javaargs`. The 
chromedriver is also `chromedriver.exe` in windows so this may cause an issue

```
library(RSelenium)
selServ <- startServer(args = c("-port 4456"), javaargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/Users/john/Documents/chromedriver.exe"), 
                       invisible = FALSE) 
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName="chrome", port=4456)
remDr$open()
```

The functions `startServer` and `checkForServer` are deprecated. I would recommend using a Docker container to run a SeleniumServer/chromedriver.

```
docker run -d -p 5901:5900 -p 127.0.0.1:4456:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:2.53.1
```

then you can run as before

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName="chrome", port=4456)
remDr$open()
```

See http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker for more details.